# Changing the RAM of lenovo workstaion from 8GB stick to 32GB

Tags: memory, ecc, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have Lenevo P700
It supports this memory . This is ram which is currently inside

https://postimg.cc/Ny2WQR8w

THis is what i find from google it supports 32GB
https://www.compuram.biz/memory/lenovo/desktop-workstation/thinkstation/p-series/p700/32gb-4x70g78059-x678c.htm

I want to buy this and not sure if its same or not
https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/go?https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com.au%2Fitm%2FSKHYNIX-32GB-PC4-2133P-DDR4-17000-2133MHz-2DRx4-HMA84GL7MMR4N-TF-Dell-HP-RAM-MEM%2F333707469827

Also is it possible that i can buy single stick to test if it works or i have to buy 2 sticks together in pair to make it work ? i want o buy 8 4 sticks

Comment: Well as first answer says let expert to do it, thats why i asked here :) . i have done the work to list my findings to make work easy for experts

Comment: Go to https://www.crucial.com

Comment: That didn't help , they will recommend their partners only , i want to buy from ebay and have to make sure if it will work. I was thinking guys here  can help me out. I have provided all information required here

Comment: Hardware Shopping is off topic. So we won't recommend anything for you. We've given you the links you need to make your own decision.